# A way to update gimp plugins on OSX all at once

Tags: macos, python, html, gimp

I'm using GIMP 2.8.16 and `py-slice.py` keeps throwing errors for layered grouped psd files and its preventing me from exporting it to web.

I am simply trying to send my sliced image to web with no avail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 736, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 360, in run_script
    _set_defaults(proc_name, params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 350, in _set_defaults
    gimpshelf.shelf[key] = defaults
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpshelf.py", line 84, in __setitem__
    p.dump(value)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle GroupLayer objects
```

Runtime Error Traceback if I merge down the Layer Group

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 736, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/py-slice.py", line 119, in pyslice
    left, right, top, bottom, i, j, ""))
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/py-slice.py", line 181, in slice
    pdb.gimp_file_save(temp_image, temp_drawable, filename, filename)
RuntimeError: Procedure 'gimp-file-save' has been called with an invalid ID for argument 'drawable'. Most likely a plug-in is trying to work on a layer that doesn't exist any longer.
```

Error with the bounds/area of the image if I pick the bottom image within an unmerged group:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 736, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/py-slice.py", line 126, in pyslice
    left, right, top, bottom, i, j, postfix))
  File "/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/py-slice.py", line 174, in slice
    temp_image.crop(right - left, bottom - top, left, top)
error: could not crop image (ID 412) to 250x170, offset 50, 881
```

Comment: Sorry - the pyslice plug-ins just was not updated on the 2.8 release to support layer groups.

Comment: So - what resut yu actually get if you merge your layer groups (all of them) before running py-slice?

Comment: @jsbueno works fine, though at that point I realized it was wiser to toggle my layers and use that to build up the prototype from scratch using code